# Can anyone sort faster than this?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

**I was able to write an even faster sort for integers!**
It sorts faster than the array can be generated.  It works by declaring an array to be of length equal to the max value of the integer array to be sorted and initialized to zero.  Then, the array to be sorted is looped through using its values as an index to the counting array - which increments each time the value is encountered.  Subsequently, the counting array is looped through and assigns its index the counted number of times to the input/output array in order.
Code below:

```
SUBROUTINE icountSORT(arrA, nA)
  ! This is a count sort.  It counts the frequency of
  ! each element in the integer array to be sorted using
  ! an array with a length of MAXVAL(arrA)+1 such that
  ! 0's are counted at index 1, 1's are counted at index 2,
  ! etc.
  !
  ! ~ Derrel Walters
  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER(KIND=8),INTENT(IN) :: nA
  INTEGER(KIND=8),DIMENSION(nA),INTENT(INOUT) :: arrA

  INTEGER(KIND=8),ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:) :: arrB
  INTEGER(KIND=8) :: i, j, k, maxA
  INTEGER ::  iStat

  maxA = MAXVAL(arrA)
  ALLOCATE(arrB(maxA+1),STAT=iStat)

  arrB = 0

  DO i = 1, nA
    arrB(arrA(i)+1) = arrB(arrA(i)+1) + 1
  END DO

  k = 1
  DO i = 1, SIZE(arrB)
    DO j = 1, arrB(i)
      arrA(k) = i - 1
      k = k + 1
    END DO
  END DO

END SUBROUTINE icountSORT
```

Posting more evidence.  [nlogn predicts too high execution times at large array sizes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqnxf.jpg)  Further, the Fortran program posted near the end of this question writes the array (unsorted and sorted) to files and posts the write and sort times.  **File writing is a known O(n) process.  The sort runs faster than the file writing all the way to the largest arrays.  If the sort was running at O(nlogn), at some point, the sorting time would cross the write time and become longer at large array sizes.**  Therefore, it has been shown that this sort routine executes with O(n) time complexity.

**I've added a complete Fortran program for compilation at the bottom of this post such that the output can be reproduced.  The execution times are linear.**

More timing data in a clearer format using the code below from a Debian environment in Win 10:

```
dwalters@Lapper3:~/PROGRAMMING/DATA-WATER$ for (( i=100000; i<=50000000; i=2*i )); do ./derrelSORT-example.py $i; done | awk  'BEGIN {print "N      Time(s)"}; {if ($1=="Creating") {printf $4" "} else if ($1=="Sorting" && $NF=="seconds") {print $3}}'
N      Time(s)
100000 0.01
200000 0.02
400000 0.04
800000 0.08
1600000 0.17
3200000 0.35
6400000 0.76
12800000 1.59
25600000 3.02
```

This code executes linearly with respect to the number of elements (integer example given here).  It achieves this by exponentially increasing the size of the sorted chunks as the (merge)sort proceeds.  To facilitate the exponentially growing chunks:

1. The number of iterations needs to be calculated before the sort begins
2. Indices transformations need to be derived for the chunks (language specific depending upon the indexing protocol) for passage to merge()
3. Gracefully handle the remainder at the tail of the list when the chunk size is not evenly divisible by a power of 2

With these things in mind and starting, traditionally, by merging pairs of single value arrays, the merged chunks can be grown from 2 to 4 to 8 to 16 to --- to 2^n.  This single case is the exception that breaks the speed limit of O(nlogn) time complexity for comparative sorts.  This routine sorts linearly with respect to the number of elements to be sorted.

Can anyone sort faster? ;)

Fortran Code (derrelSort.f90):

```
! Derrel Walters © 2019
! These sort routines were written by Derrel Walters ~ 2019-01-23


SUBROUTINE iSORT(arrA, nA)
  ! This implementation of derrelSORT is for integers,
  ! but the same principles apply for other datatypes.
  !
  ! ~ Derrel Walters
  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER(KIND=8),INTENT(IN) :: nA
  INTEGER,DIMENSION(nA),INTENT(INOUT) :: arrA

  INTEGER,DIMENSION(nA) :: arrB
  INTEGER(KIND=8) :: lowIDX, highIDX, midIDX
  INTEGER ::  iStat
  INTEGER(KIND=8) :: i, j, A, B, C, thisHigh, mergeSize, nLoops
  INTEGER,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE :: iterMark
  LOGICAL,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE :: moreToGo

  arrB = arrA
  mergeSize = 2
  lowIDX = 1 - mergeSize
  highIDX = 0

  nLoops = INT(LOG(REAL(nA))/LOG(2.0))
  ALLOCATE(iterMark(nLoops), moreToGo(nLoops), STAT=iStat)
  moreToGo = .FALSE.
  iterMark = 0

  DO i = 1, nLoops
    iterMark(i) = FLOOR(REAL(nA)/2**i)
    IF (MOD(nA, 2**i) > 0) THEN
      moreToGo(i) = .TRUE.
      iterMark(i) = iterMark(i) + 1
    END IF
  END DO

  DO i = 1, nLoops
      DO j = 1, iterMark(i)
        A = 0
        B = 1
        C = 0
        lowIDX = lowIDX + mergeSize
        highIDX = highIDX + mergeSize
        midIDX = (lowIDX + highIDX + 1) / 2
        thisHigh = highIDX
        IF (j == iterMark(i).AND.moreToGo(i)) THEN
          lowIDX = lowIDX - mergeSize
          highIDX = highIDX - mergeSize
          midIDX = (lowIDX + highIDX + 1) / 2
          A = midIDX - lowIDX
          B = 2
          C = nA - 2*highIDX + midIDX - 1
          thisHigh = nA
        END IF
        CALL imerge(arrA(lowIDX:midIDX-1+A), B*(midIDX-lowIDX),    &
                    arrA(midIDX+A:thisHigh), highIDX-midIDX+1+C,   &
                    arrB(lowIDX:thisHigh), thisHigh-lowIDX+1)
        arrA(lowIDX:thisHigh) = arrB(lowIDX:thisHigh)
      END DO
      mergeSize = 2*mergeSize
      lowIDX = 1 - mergeSize
      highIDX = 0
  END DO

END SUBROUTINE iSORT

SUBROUTINE imerge(arrA, nA, arrB, nB, arrC, nC)
  ! This merge is a faster merge.  Array A arrives
  ! just to the left of Array B, and Array C is
  ! filled from both ends simultaneously - while
  ! still preserving the stability of the sort.
  ! The derrelSORT routine is so fast, that
  ! the merge does not affect the O(n) time
  ! complexity of the sort in practice
  !
  ! ~ Derrel Walters
  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER(KIND=8),INTENT(IN) :: nA, nB , nC

  INTEGER,DIMENSION(nA),INTENT(IN) :: arrA
  INTEGER,DIMENSION(nB),INTENT(IN) :: arrB
  INTEGER,DIMENSION(nC),INTENT(INOUT) :: arrC

  INTEGER(KIND=8) :: i, j, k, x, y, z

  arrC = 0
  i = 1
  j = 1
  k = 1
  x = nA
  y = nB
  z = nC

  DO
    IF (i > x .OR. j > y) EXIT
    IF (arrB(j) < arrA(i)) THEN
      arrC(k) = arrB(j)
      j = j + 1
    ELSE
      arrC(k) = arrA(i)
      i = i + 1
    END IF
    IF (arrA(x) > arrB(y)) THEN
      arrC(z) = arrA(x)
      x = x - 1
    ELSE
      arrC(z) = arrB(y)
      y = y - 1
    END IF
    k = k + 1
    z = z - 1
  END DO

  IF (i <= x) THEN
    DO
      IF (i > x) EXIT
        arrC(k) = arrA(i)
        i = i + 1
        k = k + 1
    END DO
  ELSEIF (j <= y) THEN
    DO
      IF (j > y) EXIT
        arrC(k) = arrB(j)
        j = j + 1
        k = k + 1
    END DO
  END IF
END SUBROUTINE imerge
```

Times using f2py3 to convert the above fortran file (derrelSORT.f90) into something callable in python.  Here is the python code and times it produced (derrelSORT-example.py):

```
#!/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import derrelSORT as dS
import time as t
import random as rdm
import sys

try:
  array_len = int(sys.argv[1])
except IndexError:
  array_len = 100000000

# Create an array with array_len elements
print(50*'-')
print("Creating array of", array_len, "random integers.")
t0 = t.time()
x = np.asfortranarray(np.array([round(100000*rdm.random(),0)
                      for i in range(array_len)]).astype(np.int32))
t1 = t.time()
print('Creation time:', round(t1-t0, 2), 'seconds')


# Sort the array using derrelSORT
print("Sorting the array with derrelSORT.")
t0 = t.time()
dS.isort(x, len(x))
t1 = t.time()
print('Sorting time:', round(t1-t0, 2), 'seconds')
print(50*'-')
```

Output from the command line.  Please note the times.

```
dwalters@Lapper3:~/PROGRAMMING/DATA-WATER$ ./derrelSORT-example.py 1000000
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 1000000 random integers.
Creation time: 0.78 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 0.1 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
dwalters@Lapper3:~/PROGRAMMING/DATA-WATER$ ./derrelSORT-example.py 10000000
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 10000000 random integers.
Creation time: 8.1 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 1.07 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
dwalters@Lapper3:~/PROGRAMMING/DATA-WATER$ ./derrelSORT-example.py 20000000
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 20000000 random integers.
Creation time: 15.73 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 2.21 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
dwalters@Lapper3:~/PROGRAMMING/DATA-WATER$ ./derrelSORT-example.py 40000000
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 40000000 random integers.
Creation time: 31.64 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 4.39 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
dwalters@Lapper3:~/PROGRAMMING/DATA-WATER$ ./derrelSORT-example.py 80000000
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 80000000 random integers.
Creation time: 64.03 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 8.92 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
dwalters@Lapper3:~/PROGRAMMING/DATA-WATER$ ./derrelSORT-example.py 160000000
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 160000000 random integers.
Creation time: 129.56 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 18.04 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
```

More output:

```
dwalters@Lapper3:~/PROGRAMMING/DATA-WATER$ for (( i=100000; i<=500000000; i=2*i )); do
> ./derrelSORT-example.py $i
> done
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 100000 random integers.
Creation time: 0.08 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 0.01 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 200000 random integers.
Creation time: 0.16 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 0.02 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 400000 random integers.
Creation time: 0.32 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 0.04 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 800000 random integers.
Creation time: 0.68 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 0.08 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 1600000 random integers.
Creation time: 1.25 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 0.15 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 3200000 random integers.
Creation time: 2.57 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 0.32 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 6400000 random integers.
Creation time: 5.23 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 0.66 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 12800000 random integers.
Creation time: 10.09 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 1.35 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 25600000 random integers.
Creation time: 20.25 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 2.74 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 51200000 random integers.
Creation time: 41.84 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 5.62 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 102400000 random integers.
Creation time: 93.19 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 11.49 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 204800000 random integers.
Creation time: 167.55 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 24.13 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
Creating array of 409600000 random integers.
Creation time: 340.84 seconds
Sorting the array with derrelSORT.
Sorting time: 47.21 seconds
--------------------------------------------------
```

When the array size doubles, the time doubles - as demonstrated.  Thus, Mr. Mischel's initial assessment was incorrect.  The reason why is because that, while the outer loop determines the number of cycles at each chunk size (which is log2(n)), the inner loop counter **decreases exponentially** as the sort proceeds.  The proverbial proof is the pudding, however.  The times demonstrate the linearity clearly.

### If anyone needs any assistance reproducing the results, please let me know.  I'm happy to help.

The Fortran program found at the end of this is an as-is copy of that I wrote in 2019.  It is meant to be used on the command-line.  To compile it:

1. Copy the fortran code to a file with an .f90 extension
2. Compile the code using a command, such as:

```
gfortran -o derrelSORT-ex.x derrelSORT.f90
```

3. Give yourself permission to run the executable:

```
chmod u+x derrelSORT-ex.x
```

4. Execute the program from the command-line with or without an integer argument:

```
./derrelSORT-ex.x
```

or

```
./derrelSORT-ex.x 10000000
```

The output should look something like this (here, I've used a bash c-style loop to call the command repeatedly).  **Notice that as the array sizes double with each iteration, the execution time also doubles.**

```
SORT-RESEARCH$ for (( i=100000; i<500000000; i=2*i )); do
> ./derrelSORT-2022.x $i
> done

Derrel Walters © 2019

Demonstrating derrelSORT©
WARNING: This program can produce LARGE files!

Generating random array of length:           100000
Time =    0.0000 seconds
Writing Array to rand-in.txt:
Time =    0.0312 seconds
Sorting the Array
Time =    0.0156 seconds
Writing Array to rand-sorted-out.txt:
Time =    0.0469 seconds


Derrel Walters © 2019

Demonstrating derrelSORT©
WARNING: This program can produce LARGE files!

Generating random array of length:           200000
Time =    0.0000 seconds
Writing Array to rand-in.txt:
Time =    0.0625 seconds
Sorting the Array
Time =    0.0312 seconds
Writing Array to rand-sorted-out.txt:
Time =    0.0312 seconds


Derrel Walters © 2019

Demonstrating derrelSORT©
WARNING: This program can produce LARGE files!

Generating random array of length:           400000
Time =    0.0156 seconds
Writing Array to rand-in.txt:
Time =    0.1250 seconds
Sorting the Array
Time =    0.0625 seconds
Writing Array to rand-sorted-out.txt:
Time =    0.0938 seconds


Derrel Walters © 2019

Demonstrating derrelSORT©
WARNING: This program can produce LARGE files!

Generating random array of length:           800000
Time =    0.0156 seconds
Writing Array to rand-in.txt:
Time =    0.2344 seconds
Sorting the Array
Time =    0.1406 seconds
Writing Array to rand-sorted-out.txt:
Time =    0.2031 seconds


Derrel Walters © 2019

Demonstrating derrelSORT©
WARNING: This program can produce LARGE files!

Generating random array of length:          1600000
Time =    0.0312 seconds
Writing Array to rand-in.txt:
Time =    0.4219 seconds
Sorting the Array
Time =    0.2969 seconds
Writing Array to rand-sorted-out.txt:
Time =    0.3906 seconds


Derrel Walters © 2019

Demonstrating derrelSORT©
WARNING: This program can produce LARGE files!

Generating random array of length:          3200000
Time =    0.0625 seconds
Writing Array to rand-in.txt:
Time =    0.8281 seconds
Sorting the Array
Time =    0.6562 seconds
Writing Array to rand-sorted-out.txt:
Time =    0.7969 seconds


Derrel Walters © 2019

Demonstrating derrelSORT©
WARNING: This program can produce LARGE files!

Generating random array of length:          6400000
Time =    0.0938 seconds
Writing Array to rand-in.txt:
Time =    1.5938 seconds
Sorting the Array
Time =    1.3281 seconds
Writing Array to rand-sorted-out.txt:
Time =    1.6406 seconds


Derrel Walters © 2019

Demonstrating derrelSORT©
WARNING: This program can produce LARGE files!

Generating random array of length:         12800000
Time =    0.2500 seconds
Writing Array to rand-in.txt:
Time =    3.3906 seconds
Sorting the Array
Time =    2.7031 seconds
Writing Array to rand-sorted-out.txt:
Time =    3.2656 seconds


Derrel Walters © 2019

Demonstrating derrelSORT©
WARNING: This program can produce LARGE files!

Generating random array of length:         25600000
Time =    0.4062 seconds
Writing Array to rand-in.txt:
Time =    6.6250 seconds
Sorting the Array
Time =    5.6094 seconds
Writing Array to rand-sorted-out.txt:
Time =    6.5312 seconds


Derrel Walters © 2019

Demonstrating derrelSORT©
WARNING: This program can produce LARGE files!

Generating random array of length:         51200000
Time =    0.8281 seconds
Writing Array to rand-in.txt:
Time =   13.2656 seconds
Sorting the Array
Time =   11.5000 seconds
Writing Array to rand-sorted-out.txt:
Time =   13.1719 seconds


Derrel Walters © 2019

Demonstrating derrelSORT©
WARNING: This program can produce LARGE files!

Generating random array of length:        102400000
Time =    1.6406 seconds
Writing Array to rand-in.txt:
Time =   26.3750 seconds
Sorting the Array
Time =   23.3438 seconds
Writing Array to rand-sorted-out.txt:
Time =   27.0625 seconds


Derrel Walters © 2019

Demonstrating derrelSORT©
WARNING: This program can produce LARGE files!

Generating random array of length:        204800000
Time =    3.3438 seconds
Writing Array to rand-in.txt:
Time =   53.1094 seconds
Sorting the Array
Time =   47.3750 seconds
Writing Array to rand-sorted-out.txt:
Time =   52.8906 seconds


Derrel Walters © 2019

Demonstrating derrelSORT©
WARNING: This program can produce LARGE files!

Generating random array of length:        409600000
Time =    6.6562 seconds
Writing Array to rand-in.txt:
Time =  105.1875 seconds
Sorting the Array
Time =   99.5938 seconds
Writing Array to rand-sorted-out.txt:
Time =  109.9062 seconds
```

This is the program as-is from 2019 without modification:

```
SORT-RESEARCH$ cat derrelSORT.f90
! Derrel Walters © 2019
! These sort routines were written by Derrel Walters ~ 2019-01-23

PROGRAM sort_test
  ! This program demonstrates a linear sort routine
  ! by generating a random array (here integer), writing it
  ! to a file 'rand-in.txt', sorting it with an
  ! implementation of derrelSORT (here for integers -
  ! where the same principles apply for other applicable
  ! datatypes), and finally, printing the sorted array
  ! to a file 'rand-sorted-out.txt'.
  !
  ! To the best understanding of the author, the expert
  ! consensus is that a comparative sort can, at best,
  ! be done with O(nlogn) time complexity. Here a sort
  ! is demonstrated which experimentally runs O(n).
  !
  ! Such time complexity is currently considered impossible
  ! for a sort. Using this sort, extremely large amounts of data can be
  ! sorted on any modern computer using a single processor core -
  ! provided the computer has enough memory to hold the array! For example,
  ! the sorting time for a given array will be on par (perhaps less than)
  ! what it takes the same computer to write the array to a file.
  !
  ! ~ Derrel Walters

  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER,PARAMETER :: in_unit = 21
  INTEGER,PARAMETER :: out_unit = 23

  INTEGER,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE :: iArrA
  REAL,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE :: rArrA
  CHARACTER(LEN=15) :: cDims
  CHARACTER(LEN=80) :: ioMsgStr
  INTEGER(KIND=8) :: nDims, i
  INTEGER :: iStat
  REAL :: start, finish

  WRITE(*,*) ''
  WRITE(*,'(A)') 'Derrel Walters © 2019'
  WRITE(*,*) ''
  WRITE(*,'(A)') 'Demonstrating derrelSORT©'
  WRITE(*,'(A)') 'WARNING: This program can produce LARGE files!'
  WRITE(*,*) ''

  CALL GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT(1, cDims)
  IF (cDims == '') THEN
    nDims = 1000000
  ELSE
    READ(cDims,'(1I15)') nDims
  END IF
  ALLOCATE(iArrA(nDims),rArrA(nDims),STAT=iStat)

  WRITE(*,'(A,1X,1I16)') 'Generating random array of length:', nDims
  CALL CPU_TIME(start)
  CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(rArrA)
  iArrA = INT(rArrA*1000000)
  CALL CPU_TIME(finish)
  WRITE(*,'(A,1X,f9.4,1X,A)') 'Time =',finish-start,'seconds'
  DEALLOCATE(rArrA,STAT=iStat)

  WRITE(*,'(A)') 'Writing Array to rand-in.txt: '
  OPEN(UNIT=in_unit,FILE='rand-in.txt',STATUS='REPLACE',ACTION='WRITE',IOSTAT=iStat,IOMSG=ioMsgStr)
  IF (iStat /= 0) THEN
    WRITE(*,'(A)') ioMsgStr
  ELSE
    CALL CPU_TIME(start)
    DO i=1, nDims
      WRITE(in_unit,*) iArrA(i)
    END DO
    CLOSE(in_unit)
    CALL CPU_TIME(finish)
    WRITE(*,'(A,1X,f9.4,1X,A)') 'Time =',finish-start,'seconds'
  END IF
  WRITE(*,'(A)') 'Sorting the Array'

  CALL CPU_TIME(start)
  CALL iderrelSORT(iArrA, nDims) !! SIZE(iArrA))
  CALL CPU_TIME(finish)
  WRITE(*,'(A,1X,f9.4,1X,A)') 'Time =',finish-start,'seconds'

  WRITE(*,'(A)') 'Writing Array to rand-sorted-out.txt: '
  OPEN(UNIT=out_unit,FILE='rand-sorted-out.txt',STATUS='REPLACE',ACTION='WRITE',IOSTAT=iStat,IOMSG=ioMsgStr)
  IF (iStat /= 0) THEN
    WRITE(*,'(A)') ioMsgStr
  ELSE
    CALL CPU_TIME(start)
    DO i=1, nDims
      WRITE(out_unit,*) iArrA(i)
    END DO
    CLOSE(out_unit)
    CALL CPU_TIME(finish)
    WRITE(*,'(A,1X,f9.4,1X,A)') 'Time =',finish-start,'seconds'
  END IF
  WRITE(*,*) ''

END PROGRAM sort_test

SUBROUTINE iderrelSORT(arrA, nA)
  ! This implementation of derrelSORT is for integers,
  ! but the same principles apply for other datatypes.
  !
  ! ~ Derrel Walters
  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER(KIND=8),INTENT(IN) :: nA
  INTEGER,DIMENSION(nA),INTENT(INOUT) :: arrA

  INTEGER,DIMENSION(nA) :: arrB
  INTEGER(KIND=8) :: lowIDX, highIDX, midIDX
  INTEGER ::  iStat
  INTEGER(KIND=8) :: i, j, A, B, C, thisHigh, mergeSize, nLoops
  INTEGER,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE :: iterMark
  LOGICAL,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE :: moreToGo

  arrB = arrA
  mergeSize = 2
  lowIDX = 1 - mergeSize
  highIDX = 0

  nLoops = INT(LOG(REAL(nA))/LOG(2.0))
  ALLOCATE(iterMark(nLoops), moreToGo(nLoops), STAT=iStat)
  moreToGo = .FALSE.
  iterMark = 0

  DO i = 1, nLoops
    iterMark(i) = FLOOR(REAL(nA)/2**i)
    IF (MOD(nA, 2**i) > 0) THEN
      moreToGo(i) = .TRUE.
      iterMark(i) = iterMark(i) + 1
    END IF
  END DO

  DO i = 1, nLoops
      DO j = 1, iterMark(i)
        A = 0
        B = 1
        C = 0
        lowIDX = lowIDX + mergeSize
        highIDX = highIDX + mergeSize
        midIDX = (lowIDX + highIDX + 1) / 2
        thisHigh = highIDX
        IF (j == iterMark(i).AND.moreToGo(i)) THEN
          lowIDX = lowIDX - mergeSize
          highIDX = highIDX - mergeSize
          midIDX = (lowIDX + highIDX + 1) / 2
          A = midIDX - lowIDX
          B = 2
          C = nA - 2*highIDX + midIDX - 1
          thisHigh = nA
        END IF
!! The traditional merge can also be used (see subroutine for comment). !!
!                                                                        !
!        CALL imerge(arrA(lowIDX:midIDX-1+A), B*(midIDX-lowIDX),   &     !
!                    arrA(midIDX+A:thisHigh), highIDX-midIDX+1+C, &      !
!                    arrB(lowIDX:thisHigh), thisHigh-lowIDX+1)           !
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        CALL imerge2(arrA(lowIDX:midIDX-1+A), B*(midIDX-lowIDX),   &
                    arrA(midIDX+A:thisHigh), highIDX-midIDX+1+C,   &
                    arrB(lowIDX:thisHigh), thisHigh-lowIDX+1)
        arrA(lowIDX:thisHigh) = arrB(lowIDX:thisHigh)
      END DO
      mergeSize = 2*mergeSize
      lowIDX = 1 - mergeSize
      highIDX = 0
  END DO

END SUBROUTINE iderrelSORT

SUBROUTINE imerge(arrA, nA, arrB, nB, arrC, nC)
  ! This merge is a traditional merge that places
  ! the lowest element first. The form that the
  ! time complexity takes, O(n), is not affected
  ! by the merge routine - yet this routine
  ! does not run as fast as the merge used in
  ! imerge2.
  !
  ! ~Derrel Walters
  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER(KIND=8),INTENT(IN) :: nA, nB , nC

  INTEGER,DIMENSION(nA),INTENT(IN) :: arrA
  INTEGER,DIMENSION(nB),INTENT(IN) :: arrB
  INTEGER,DIMENSION(nC),INTENT(INOUT) :: arrC

  INTEGER(KIND=8) :: i, j, k

  arrC = 0
  i = 1
  j = 1
  k = 1

  DO
    IF (i > nA .OR. j > NB) EXIT
    IF (arrB(j) < arrA(i)) THEN
      arrC(k) = arrB(j)
      j = j + 1
    ELSE
      arrC(k) = arrA(i)
      i = i + 1
    END IF
    k = k + 1
  END DO

  IF (i <= nA) THEN
    DO
      IF (i > nA) EXIT
        arrC(k) = arrA(i)
        i = i + 1
        k = k + 1
    END DO
  ELSEIF (j <= nB) THEN
    DO
      IF (j > nB) EXIT
        arrC(k) = arrB(j)
        j = j + 1
        k = k + 1
    END DO
  END IF

END SUBROUTINE imerge

SUBROUTINE imerge2(arrA, nA, arrB, nB, arrC, nC)
  ! This merge is a faster merge.  Array A arrives
  ! just to the left of Array B, and Array C is
  ! filled from both ends simultaneously - while
  ! still preserving the stability of the sort.
  ! The derrelSORT routine is so fast, that
  ! the merge does not affect the O(n) time
  ! complexity of the sort in practice
  ! (perhaps, making its execution more linear
  ! at small numbers of elements).
  !
  ! ~ Derrel Walters
  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER(KIND=8),INTENT(IN) :: nA, nB , nC

  INTEGER,DIMENSION(nA),INTENT(IN) :: arrA
  INTEGER,DIMENSION(nB),INTENT(IN) :: arrB
  INTEGER,DIMENSION(nC),INTENT(INOUT) :: arrC

  INTEGER(KIND=8) :: i, j, k, x, y, z

  arrC = 0
  i = 1
  j = 1
  k = 1
  x = nA
  y = nB
  z = nC

  DO
    IF (i > x .OR. j > y) EXIT
    IF (arrB(j) < arrA(i)) THEN
      arrC(k) = arrB(j)
      j = j + 1
    ELSE
      arrC(k) = arrA(i)
      i = i + 1
    END IF
    IF (arrA(x) > arrB(y)) THEN
      arrC(z) = arrA(x)
      x = x - 1
    ELSE
      arrC(z) = arrB(y)
      y = y - 1
    END IF
    k = k + 1
    z = z - 1
  END DO

  IF (i <= x) THEN
    DO
      IF (i > x) EXIT
        arrC(k) = arrA(i)
        i = i + 1
        k = k + 1
    END DO
  ELSEIF (j <= y) THEN
    DO
      IF (j > y) EXIT
        arrC(k) = arrB(j)
        j = j + 1
        k = k + 1
    END DO
  END IF
END SUBROUTINE imerge2
```

MOAR data using the Fortran version.  Anyone into straight lines?

```
SORT-RESEARCH$ for (( i=100000; i<500000000; i=2*i )); do ./derrelSORT-2022.x $i; done | awk 'BEGIN {old_1="Derrel"; print "N      Time(s)"};{if ($1 == "Generating") {printf $NF" "; old_1=$1} else if (old_1 == "Sorting") {print $3; old_1=$1} else {old_1=$1}}'
N      Time(s)
100000 0.0000
200000 0.0312
400000 0.0625
800000 0.1562
1600000 0.2969
3200000 0.6250
6400000 1.3594
12800000 2.7500
25600000 5.5625
51200000 11.8906
102400000 23.3750
204800000 47.3750
409600000 96.4531
```

Appears linear, doesn't it? ;)
[Fortran sorting times from above plotted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VZDG.jpg)

Comment: Riemann hypothesis next?....

Comment: I don't see any reason to think that your double-ended merge would be faster than a standard one.  Quite the opposite.  Although they should both perform pretty close to the same number of steps, a single-ended (and forward-only) merge will tend to be more cache-friendly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  In practice, the double-ended merge ran faster.  For example, when executing the above Fortran code calling the traditional merge routine, the sort takes precisely the same time as writing the array to the file (an O(n) process, btw).  When using the double edge merge, it executes in less time than the read/write statements.

Comment: @MitchWheat Perhaps, if I can ever find the time.  Inflation has my axe always on the grind stone. ;)

Comment: @DJWalters If you somehow created a linear comparison sort, your inflation worries would be over. I would be the first to congratulate you on your achievement. Unfortunately, what you demonstrate here is not a linear comparison sort.

Comment: @DJWalters not all operations are executed in the same amount of time. It might very well be that `n log n` operations on an in-memory array are faster than `n` write operations on an SSD for practical values of `n`.

Comment: I took the Fortran program presented in the question and compiled it, unmodified, with `gfortran -O3` (from version 8.5.0 of the GCC suite).  Running it on sample sizes 100,000; 1,000,000; 10,000,000; and 100,000,000 exhibited distinct superlinear scaling, with execution time ratios for the sorting stage (as reported by the program) vs N=100,000 of 1.00, 11.6, 144, 1500.  That looks pretty bad for your linear-scaling hypothesis, but reasonable for N log N.

Comment: Also, yes, I can sort faster than that.  At minimum, I can modify your code to cut its execution time on an input of size 100,000,000 by about 20%.  Time savings comes mostly from eliminating a lot of unnecessary writes, such as zero initialization of storage that is going to be overwritten anyway, and copying arrB back to arrA after every merge pass instead of *merging* it back the other direction.  Using array-slice assignment for copying instead of loops helps a bit, too, plus a few other odds & ends.

Comment: I see a "merge loop body" unrolled twice. Working from both ends degrades locality.

Comment: [Counting sort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#History) isn't new, either.

Comment: `OPEN(UNIT=in_unit,…,ACTION='WRITE',…)` & `WRITE(in_unit,*) iArrA(i)` looks inconsistent.

Comment: With the `moreToGo` mojo, what would convince me `iderrelSORT` *does* sort?

Comment: This 'question' still makes me laugh!

Answer (score 10):

Your algorithm is not O(n). Your calculated number of loops (`nLoops`) is `log2(n)`. The number of inner loops (the values in `iterMark`) will be essentially n/2, n/4, n/8, etc. But the segment sizes really don't matter because every time through the outer loop you look at every item in the list.

No matter how you obfuscate it, you're doing log2(n) passes over n items: O(n log n).

Your code is a fairly standard merge sort, which is proven to be O(n log n). It's well proven that the general case for comparison sorts is O(n log n). Sure, some algorithms can sort some specific cases more quickly. Conversely, the same algorithms have pathological cases that will take O(n^2). Other comparison sorts (heap sort, merge sort, for example) are not highly subject to the order of items. But in the general case comparison sorts make on the order of n log n comparisons. See [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect0913.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eavrim/451f11/lectures/lect0913.pdf) for a detailed explanation.

But don't take my word for it. You can easily test yourself by doing some simple timings. Time how long it takes to sort, say, 100K items. If your algorithm is indeed O(n), then it should take approximately twice as long to sort 200K items, and ten times as long to sort 1 million items. But if it's O(n log n), as I suspect, then the timings will be somewhat longer.

Consider: log(2) of 100K is 16.61. log(2) of 200K is 17.61. So sorting 100K items (if the algorithm is O(log n)) will take time proportional to 100K * 16.61. Sorting 200K items will take time proportional to 200K * 17.71. Doing the arithmetic:

```
100K * 16.61 = 1,661,000
200K * 17.61 = 3,522,000
```

So 200K items will take approximately 2.12 times (3,522,000/1,661,000) as long. Or, about 10% longer than if the algorithm is linear.

If you're still unsure, pump it up to a million items. If the algorithm is linear, then a million items will take 10x the time that 100K items took. If it's O(n log n), then it will take 12 times as long.

```
1M * 19.93 = 19,930,000
(19,930,000 / 1,661,000) = 11.9987 (call it 12)
```

Comment: It's executes linearly, brother.  When I first wrote it, I tested it against the Linux command-line built-in sort program, and my sort was faster using a single core than Linux sort was running in parallel.  The tests were run on the research computer clusters at UA-Fayetteville.  Did you even run the code before commenting?

Comment: I added times to the post, Mr. Mischel, as you requested.  The code is also posted.  If further instructions are needed to reproduce the results, please let me know.  As written, the routine sorts the array in place.

Comment: @DJWalters In your data set, your numbers for time to sort per element rise from 1.56e-07 seconds to 2.4314892578125e-07 seconds.  This is an increase of about 55.9%.  It is slightly less than the theoretical 72.2% from `O(n log(n))` because you spend some time doing things like copying data, which grows linearly. But you HAVE NOT broken the laws of math by making a comparison sort that scales linearly. You really, really, really have not.

Comment: @btilly I did not claim to break any laws of math.  Look at the plot I shared and convince me the execution times aren't linear.  As I said, the proof is in the pudding, sir.  What I did say is that there happens to be a case where the theoretical limit is incorrect, and I've presented ample proof that I'm correct.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: It *is* a merge sort, but of the less-common iterative variety, so it at least has that to set it apart from the "fairly standard" category.

Comment: @DJWalters The fact remains that you're doing `log2(n)` passes over `n` data items. If you can show me somehow that you're doing fewer passes over a smaller number of items then I'll take you seriously.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It's true that the iterative merge sort is less common than the recursive version, but it's shown (at least it used to be) in standard algorithm texts. I've certainly seen it used in a large number of production systems over the years. I think "fairly standard" fits.

Comment: @DJWalters And, no, I didn't run the code before commenting. As I said, what you have there is an obfuscated implementation of a fairly standard iterative merge sort. I've seen it hundreds of times and written it myself dozens of times. I don't need to run the code when a brief analysis tells me everything I need to know.

Comment: @DJWalters YOUR OWN NUMBERS show a slowdown per element in the range to expect from `O(n log(n))`.  If you instrument your code to count comparisons, that will show an even better match to theory. And, whether or not you understand it, your claim to have a comparison sort running in linear time IS IMPOSSIBLE.

Comment: You may not understand WHY it is impossible, but that is your problem, not mine.  You were given a link to https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect0913.pdf which contains a proof that it is impossible.

Comment: @JimMischel, this routine executes, in practice, with linear time.  I've now demonstrated in the post that nlogn behavior predicts too high execution times for large array lengths as those obtained experimentally.  Further, the fully functional Fortran program now included at the end of the post (executable from the command-line) creates a random array, writes it to file, sorts it, writes the sorted array to file, and posts the times.  How is it that the sort runs faster over the **entire** set of array sizes when writing to a file is known to be O(n)?  There should be convergence, brother.

Comment: @btilly, the execution times I posted prove that the sort executes linearly.  Further, as I noted to Mr. Mischel, file writing is a known O(n) process.  In the data taken from the fully functional Fortran program I posted above, you'll find that the sort runs consistently faster than the file write over the entire set of array lengths (a feat in itself).  As the array lengths increase, if the sort was running at O(nlogn) time complexity, there would be convergence in the sorting and writing times as the lengths became longer.  However, no convergence exists, sir.  Thanks.

Comment: @DJWalters Concepts you are apparently unclear on: what "proof" means, how big-O works, and how slowly log(n) grows. I'm not going to bother replying again. You are the only person who is unclear on how your code scales, and you're too busy arguing why you're right to process why you're wrong.

Comment: @DJWalters no one is saying your algorithm isn't fast. We're saying it's not linear. It running faster in practice than `n` write operations does indeed show that you've come up with an efficient algorithm. It does not show linear time complexity. Convergence in math needs to happen as you approach infinity, it doesn't have to happen for however many fixed steps you manage to run something for.

Answer (score 4):

My f2py skills are not strong, so I wrote a pure fortran wrapper for your code (posted below, if you want to check it), and the timings I got were:

```
 n                     time (s)          0.1*n/1e6       0.1*n*log(n)/1e6*log(1e6)
              1000000  0.109375000      0.100000001      0.100000001
              2000000  0.203125000      0.200000003      0.210034326
              4000000  0.453125000      0.400000006      0.440137327
              8000000  0.937500000      0.800000012      0.920411944
             16000000   1.92187500       1.60000002       1.92109859
             32000000   4.01562500       3.20000005       4.00274658
             64000000   8.26562500       6.40000010       8.32659149
            128000000   17.0468750       12.8000002       17.2953815
            256000000   35.1406250       25.6000004       35.8751564
```

This is... not looking good for your `O(n)` theory, I'm afraid.

My wrapper:

```
module m
contains
! Your code goes here
end module

program p
  use m
  implicit none

  integer(8) :: i,n
  real, allocatable :: real_array(:)
  integer, allocatable :: int_array(:)
  real :: start
  real :: stop

  real_array = [0]
  int_array = [0]

  write(*,*) "n                     time (s)          0.1*n/1e6       0.1*n*log(n)/1e6*log(1e6)"

  do i=0,30
    n = 2**i*1e6
    deallocate(real_array, int_array)
    allocate(real_array(n), int_array(n))
    call random_number(real_array)
    int_array = -huge(0)*real_array + 2.0*huge(0)

    call cpu_time(start)
    call isort(int_array, n)
    call cpu_time(stop)

    write(*,*) n, stop-start, 0.1*n/1.0e6, 0.1*n*log(1.0*n)/(1.0e6*log(1.0e6))
  enddo
end program
```

Comment: Fortran, unlike the python code, IS case-sensitive.  Unfortunately, your code, as written would not run using Fortran.  Would you like me to demonstrate?  I already have that program written, as well.

Comment: I can assure you, Fortran is [not case sensitive](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4940/z40009104490/index.html). I can also assure you my code runs.

Comment: I can't see what routine your calling with it hid away in a module.  Post the file with my routines callable where the output can be reproduced.  By the way, after looking at my fortran code, I do realize the case insensitivity now.  However, that doesn't change the fact I can't see the sorting routine your calling here.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers have explained why you do not have a linear comparison sort.

I'll try to explain why execution times will **never** prove a time complexity.

Many times you could come up with some specific cases and an algorithm that uses various CPU-specific optimizations that does its job (whether that job is sorting or something else) better than `O(n)` according to a plot: if the time for `x` items is `y`, then according to the graph the time for `2x` items is less than `2y`. And this can happen for as large of an `x` as you can fit into memory.

Still, this proves nothing about time complexity. This could be an algorithm with time complexity `O(n)`, or `O(n log n)` or maybe even `O(log n)` or `O(n*n)`.

Big-Oh notation hides the various constants that describe the number of operations performed by the algorithm, so such an algorithm could just be `O(n log n)` with a very small constant (as in, a `constant < 1`) or `O(log n)` with a huge constant.

Big-Oh also does not care about real-life aspects such as system memory or disk space or how fast some CPU executes one instruction as opposed to another. Maybe the operations you use just execute really fast on that CPU. Regardless, if you have an `O(n log n)` algorithm, for large enough `n`, you would eventually see the graph look like an `n log n` graph.

A real example of this could be the [Disjoint set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Proof_of_O(m_log*_n)_time_complexity_of_Union-Find), which uses something called an `iterated logarithm` and its complexity is `O(m log* n)`. In practice, `log* n` will be something `<= 5` for all practical values, so if you plot it for practical values, you might think it's `O(m)` with a big constant, but that's not the case.

You could change your algorithm to read each number from a different file and write it back to that file, at each step, and remove your input array completely. It wouldn't affect its time complexity, but it would definitely affect the nice execution time measurements you're seeing, because storage is obviously slower than memory. Well, they're all the same to Big-Oh.

Comment: The Fortran code I posted at the end of the program writes the arrays (sorted and unsorted) to files.  Writing is a known O(n) process.  The execution times of the write and sort are on the same order and, thus, comparable.  If the sort was executing at O(nlogn), then the execution time of the sort would converge with the write times as the array lengths grew.  However, no convergence exists.  Thanks.

Comment: Never say never, brother. QED

Comment: @DJWalters that's not what I mean be writing to files. I don't mean write the arrays to file at the end. I mean, whenever you need a number at index `i`, read it from `i.txt` instead, and when you need to write to a position `i`, write it to `i.txt` instead. This will make everything much slower, but the time complexity will remain the same.

Comment: It is never in this case by definition. I'm curious, what kind of argument would convince you that what you have is not linear?

Answer (score 3):

I don't doubt that your sort is fast, and I can believe that it compares favorably with the `sort` command-line utility.  But it is an O(N log(N)) iterative merge sort, not an O(N) sort (nor a novel algorithm).

Observe,

- Your outer loop iterates O(log(N)) times.
- On each of those iterations, the inner loop iterates O(N / 2<sup>*k*</sup>) times for some *k*.
- And the main work of each inner-loop iteration is to split O(2<sup>*k*</sup>) items into two halves and merge those together, which involves examining and moving every single item.  (And then moving them all again back to the original array.)  That costs O(2<sup>*k*</sup>) operations per inner-loop iteration.

Those factors all multiply together:

O(log(N)) * O(N / 2<sup>*k*</sup>) * O(2<sup>*k*</sup>)

The factors of 2<sup>*k*</sup> cancel each other, and you're left with O(N log(N)).  (The *k*s are functions of N, so they cannot simply be ignored as constants.)

The logarithm grows very slowly, so if you don't look too closely then it is easy to be fooled into thinking you see linear growth when it's really N log(N).  You need to look at wide ranges of values to see the superlinearity, and some is indeed visible in your data.

As for your plot, there's a problem with the result of your curve fitting: the `y` intercept is significantly negative (for the scale of the data, and especially for the concentration of points with small `y`).  Your data may fit a linear model well (if not entirely sensically), but they sure appear to fit an N log(N) model better.

Comment: O(nlogn) predicts too long execution times at large array sizes.  The evidence is posted.  The program posted at the end of the post is fully functional.  Please chart and post some actual data. Thanks.

Comment: @DJWalters, O(n log n) does not predict any particular execution time, it predicts how execution time *scales* with input size, *in the asymptotic limit*.  Algorithmic analysis, such as is presented here, is the usual and most conclusive technique for making such determinations.